# RenderTheme Mapsforge

Tags: android, xsd, render, mapsforge

I'm trying to make a custom map with mapsforge, but I have a problem with android studio 1.0.

I imported the library of mapsforge 0.5.0... mapsforge-map-0.5.0.jar...
I created the assets folder and I created rendertheme-v4.xml... so I put the next code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rendertheme xmlns="http://mapsforge.org/renderTheme"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://mapsforge.org/renderTheme ../renderTheme-v4.xsd"
    version="3" map-background="#F8F8F8">
</rendertheme>
```

I get this code to the sample code of mapsforge, so I get the error in "../renderTheme-v4.xsd"... Android studio gives me the following error:

> Cannot resolve file "../renderTheme-v4.xsd"

Answer (score 0):

You can put

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://mapsforge.org/renderTheme/renderTheme-v4.xsd
```